# crashing: _finishDecodingLayoutGuideConnections:] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller

I am working in X-code 9 beta Swift 4, and can run and build but get the following error and only a white screen loads:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myapp.logInVC _finishDecodingLayoutGuideConnections:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10251ead0'

Not sure what _finishDecodingLayoutGuideConnections is?
I checked all my selectors, but didn't see an issue. This is a login screen using Firebase, and my hope would be if login is successful it will load the View Controller.
Any help would be much appreciated!

class logInVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInSelector: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var signInLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

var isSignIn:Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func signInSelectorChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch signInSelector.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        signInLabel.text = "sign in";
    case 1:
        signInLabel.text = "create account";
    default:
        break
    }
}



@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isSignIn {
        //validation
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text
        {
            //sign in with Firebase
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { (user, error) in
                // make sure user isn't nil
                if user != nil {
                    //user is found, go to AR experience
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome" , sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    //error, check error and show message

                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //register with Firebase
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
                // make sure user isn't nil
                if user != nil {
                    //user is found, go to AR experience
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome" , sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    //error, check error, and show message
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your IBOutlets and IBActions are properly connected. The error occurs when your XiB and Class files are not properly setup.